# How to automate a complex build including multiple projects and jar creation + obfuscation for Android using Ant?

Tags: android, ant, jar, obfuscation, apk

I'm sure that this has been asked many times (as I have found many similar questions and answers) however, somehow, the solution still eludes me. Basically, I have found tutorials online but none work for me -> they are either out of date and my Ant install doesn't like the build.xml files that exist in those tutorials OR the other tutorials just don't give me all the information that I need to accomplish this (gosh, things should really be made easier).

So, say I have 3 projects -> project 'Initial', project 'DependsOnInitial', and project 'FinalDependsOnBoth'.  So, I need to create a script that automates the process of "building the 'Initial' project which depends on other, 3rd party jar files residing in its libs directory and creating an obfuscated jar file" (the .class files from the 3rd party jars don't necessarily need to be obfuscated) which can then be copied over to the 'libs' folder of the 'DependsOnInitial' project. Then, the script will "build another jar file for the 'DependsOnInitial' project which also depends on both the jar file created from 'Initial' as well as other 3rd party jars and then obfuscates the result and packages it into a jar". Finally, the script will "build the project 'FinalDependsOnBoth' which depends on the 2 jar files created as well as other 3rd party jars and obfuscates and signs the result creating an executable .apk file".

I'm actually able to do this right now with my script that I have but it seems like there is some problem in referencing the obfuscated items as my application crashes.

Also, please keep in mind that I am using the latest Android tools (I'm using Rev. 20.0.3 of the SDK tools and Rev. 14 of the SDK Platform-tools); many of the ant build.xml examples I find on the 'net are using older ant systems (my ant system will use ant.properties and local.properties to set many of it's internal values, etc.).

Preferably your reply will include a full build.xml or, otherwise, a bash script which invokes the ant on the relevant projects' build.xml files (or some combination).

(the reason for what I am doing is that the intermediate jar files will need to be distributed to other partners and therefore need to be obfuscated themselves in addition to the final application that will go to the marketplace)